# Javascript import-export and scope questions

Tags: javascript, import, scope, export

This might be quite straightforwards for some but I don't fully understand how import and export work in terms of scope.

Let's go with a really basic setup

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main id='main'></main>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```js
import hello from './hello.js'

console.log('Hello from app.js')
hello()
```

**hello.js**

```js
const hello = () => console.log('Hello from hello.js');

const greetings = document.getElementById('main')
greetings.innerHTML += 'Hello there from hello.js';

export default hello;
```

I understand why the `hello()` function works but why `hello.js` - `greetings` modifies `index.html` although that part of the code is not exported and imported to `app.js`?

When splitting code into modules, what would be the best practice that these things don't happen only if, in this case `greetings`, is imported as well?

Thanks

Comment: You maybe only exporting `hello`  but the rest of the script is still being executed. Maybe put `greetings` in its own function then `export { hello, greetings }` and then `import { hello, greetings } from hello.js`.

Comment: Because when you import `hello.js`, the entire file gets executed, try adding `console.log('something')` in `hello.js` at any line. It will call `console.log` even if you exporting only `hello` function.
So if you don't want greetings to be executed, just wrap it inside a function and export it if you want to use it outside of `hello.js.`

Comment: @bogdanoff - thanks, yes I had the impression that the entire file gets executed. If I am okay with `greetings` to be executed, is it still a good practice to leave it like this or should I always try to wrap it inside a function?

Comment: @thenubian that depends on your need, but most of the time you wrap it inside a function because  there is no way of knowing why the `<main>` got modified & you have to  manually check `hello.js` to understand it. 
So  wrap it inside a function (let say printHelloInMain ) and call it inside `app.js` that way when you read/debug you know what exactly happening and no need to open `hello.js`.
You should think it as `module`, `contained` or `independent` while writing code & that's key factor of  `code splitting`.